# Add class to li on clicking ul tag using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm clicking on ul tag and it has many li tags.. which ever li tag I click it should add a class "open" . Here is my code

```
$(document).on('click', '.navbar', function(e) { 

     $(this).find('li').addClass('open');
});
```

### Html code

```
<ul class='navbar'>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.navbar li').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).addClass('open');
});
```

Comment: I should add class to the nearst li on clicking ul

Comment: `UL` is abstract object, when you click the `LIs` you click the `UL`